# Can any one tell me about React-Redux state management?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

[image: this is the current structure of React-Redux store]

where I initialize the reducer, I have initialized the initial state like this,

```
const initialState = {
    isLogedIn: false
};
```

and after dispatch an action of USER_SIGN_IN, I got an extra node that I have initialized as shown in the picture.

```
export default (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case USER_SIGN_IN:
            return {
                ...state,
                isLogedIn: true
            };
            case USER_SIGN_UP:
                return {
                    ...state,
                    user: {
                        firstName: action.payload.firstName,
                        lastName: action.payload.lastName,
                        email: action.payload.email
                    },
                    isLogedIn: false
            };
        default:
            return {
                state
            };
    };
};
```

can anyone tell me, why this is happed in redux and how can I resolve this?

here is a GitHub repo link: https://github.com/Dawood-Shahid/TODO_Application

Comment: Is the second case of USER_SIGN_UP indented like what you have shown above or is it just a formatting issue on SO? Can you also try to wrap the case statements in curly brases like so: `case ABC: { return state }`

Comment: USER_SIGN_UP function is used to add user data to the store like: `user:{ firtNAme: 'abc', lastNAme: 'xyz', email: 'abc@gmail.com'}`. and wrap the case like `case ABC: {return state}` also provide the same result as before

Answer (score 1):

This issue is resolved when I pass the spread state to the default reducer like:
`default: return { ...state };`